# What is the correct verb to pair with „das Deo(dorant)“?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

What is the correct verb to pair with „Deodorant“ or „Deo“? By way of comparison, in (American) English, we most often *put on* deodorant or more rarely *apply*, but *use* seems a little awkward to me.

What is the correct verb in German? *Benutzen*? *Anwenden*?

Relatedly: do you need to use the definite article when talking about deodorant, or would it be considered a verbal complement (with no article)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Ich benutze (das) Deodorant.

That would be the formally correct way to say that you use the "Deodorant".

But you could also use *auftragen*:

> Ich trage (das) Deo auf.

That is correct as well, but from my experience the first one is more common.

Furthermore, "Deodorant" was also turned into a verb by itself:

> Ich deodoriere mich.

Which means "I use the Deodorant on myself". I'm not sure if that's in a dictionary, but it's used commonly.

Comment: Never ever heard deodoriere, but dictionaries list that word.

Comment: _auftragen_ is more likely if the deodorant is applied with a roll-on rather than as spray, though. Also, _verwenden_, _benutzen_, _nehmen_ or _applizieren_ are not unheard of either.

Comment: PS: _sich **mit** Deo einsprühen / einnebeln / duschen_ or _sich Deo unter die Achseln / Arme schmieren / reiben / sprühen_.

Answer (score 5):

In **informal** situations I ususally say:

> Ich brauch noch Deo.

or

> Ich muss mich noch deoen.

but this is colloquial and not correct.

More **common** is

> "ein Deo benutzen"

and more **formal** is

> "ein Deo auftragen".

There are also some more terms in use

> sich (mit Deo) einsprühen - Ich sprühe mich (mit Deo) ein.

In the example above context matters. Without mentioning "Deo" it could also be a repellent or sunshield. It implies an aerosol is in use. The following example doesn't imply what type of deo is meant:

> sich (mit Deo) beduften - Ich bedufte mich (mit Deo).

The construction "ein Deo anwenden" is not wrong but of uncommon use (at least in Northern parts of Germany).

Comment: So you use the indefinite article? Fascinating. Does "ein Deo" refer to a stick of deodorant, or the application of deodorant?

Comment: I've never heard "Ich muss mich noch deoen." before. Sounds funny

Comment: "ein Deo" is simply a deodorant, no matter if stick or aerosol. In most cases it is not clear or won't matter what specific odour or brand is meant. "Das Deo" is a specific deo - my deo or that one smelling of flowers or that specific Calvin Klein Deo. usually context and setting give a hint if a deo or that deo is meant ;)

Comment: @iris "deoen" is in no way official language. it is kinda community slang but yes, it's short and funny so we use it :-D

Comment: It should be noted that *Ich brauch noch Deo* simply means that you thing you need to use some deodorant, probably because one can smell it's necessary :-) The question, however, is how to say you're currently *applying* it.

Comment: Actually "Ich brauch noch Deo" simply says you need deodorant; that you need to *use* it is just implied from the situation. If you say "ich brauch noch Deo" in the drug store, I'd rather interpret it as "I need to buy some deodorant".

Comment: Yes, right in most situations, but as i said - it is colloquial. I heard that and use it e.g. when i'm asked to take off: "Können wir los?" - "Ja, aber ich brauch noch Deo." It doesn't matter, if it is really needed or not. I also heard "Ich muss noch Deo." This isn't even a complete sentences but in use (maybe a local thing).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to say what you do *in general* you would say

> Ich nehme (ein) Deo.

or

> Ich benutze (ein) Deo.

That's very common, especially when replying to "What do *you* do to prevent body odor?" -- "Ich nehme (ein) Deo.".

There's also a difference between "Ich nehme/benutze Deo" and "Ich nehme/benutze **das** Deo".

- "Ich nehme/benutze (ein) Deo" means: in general, as a habit, as opposed to tacking [Little Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Trees) to my armpits
- "Ich nehme/benutze **das** Deo" means: I use that particular bottle/can/brand. It's only used when you can choose between two or more and pick one of them.